# SwiftUI : Why preferenceKey is not read/called

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

From the code below, I can't figure out why Preference key is not read from the view put in background of HStack. Strangely, If I put that BGViewSetter to the Text Views inside ForEach loop, it works. Unless I have ommitted something too obvious, it looks like a bug. Anybody can confirm it? Thanks

- xcode12.2
- ios 14.2

```
struct TestRectPreference : Equatable
{
    var frame : CGRect
}

struct TestRectPreferenceKey : PreferenceKey
{
    typealias Value =  TestRectPreference
    static var defaultValue:  TestRectPreference =  TestRectPreference(frame: CGRect.zero)
    static func reduce(value: inout  TestRectPreference, nextValue: () ->  TestRectPreference)
    {
        value.frame = nextValue().frame
    }
}
struct BGViewSetter: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                .fill(Color.init(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9372549057, green: 0.3490196168, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1)))
                .preference(key: TestRectPreferenceKey.self,
                            value: TestRectPreference(frame: geometry.frame(in: .global)))
        }
    }
}


    struct FinalView : View
    {
        @State var offsetX : CGFloat = .zero
        
        @State var info = ""
        
        @State var size : CGFloat = .zero
        
        var body: some View
        {
                VStack
                {
                    Text("FinalView : \(info)")
                        
                        HStack
                        {
                            ForEach( 1 ..< 10)
                            { i in
                                Text("\(i)")
                                    .frame(width: 100)
                                    .opacity(0.8)
                            }
                        }
                        .background(BGViewSetter())
                        .animation(.easeOut)
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture()
                                .onChanged
                                { gesture in
                                    self.offsetX = gesture.translation.width
                                }
                                
                                .onEnded
                                { _ in
                                    self.offsetX = .zero
                                }
                        )
                        .offset(x: self.offsetX)
                    
                    Text("Footer")
                    Divider()
                    Spacer()
                }
                .onPreferenceChange(TestRectPreferenceKey.self)
                                    {
                                            self.size = $0.frame.height
                                            self.info = "Pref Chng : \(self.size)"
                                    }
        }
    }
    
    struct PreferenceKeyTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            FinalView()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would you show TestRectPreferenceKey code?

Comment: @Asperi , My bad. I have updated with PreferenceKey implementation.